# Where/How are Oracle Column Aliases Declared?

Tags: oracle, view, alias

I am trying to trace some information/primary keys in tables, and the normal mechanism we use to do this is through views that are nothing more than semantic layers on top of tables that have extremely cryptic column names.

As an example, the table looks like:

```
create table F3002_WH
(
  ixtbm  CHAR(9) not null,
  ixkit  NUMBER not null,
  ixmmcu CHAR(36) not null,
  ixcpnt NUMBER not null,
  ixsbnt NUMBER not null,
  ixbqty NUMBER not null,
  ixcoby CHAR(3) not null
);
```

But the views turn each of these fields into readable names, such as "TYPE_BILL" instead of "ixtbm."

However, when I look at the DDL for the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW F3002_VIEW AS
SELECT
  ixtbm, ixkit, ixmmcu, ixcpnt, ixsbnt, ixbqty, ixcoby
from F3002_WH;
```

I don't see the alias.  I would have expected to see `ixtbm as type_bill`.

So my question is where does this alias come from, and how can I tie it to the original field name without turning this into a science project?  I don't understand how it can be rendered when querying the view without being within the view code.

For what it's worth, I am using PL/SQL Developer, by All Around Automation.  I strongly suspect it is not the culprit, but in the interest of full disclosure I thought to mention it.

Comment: How are you looking at the DDL? `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` will show the view's column names, whether that match the underlying table or not, and you can see the in `user_tab_columns` for both the table and view. It would seem odd if PL/SQL Developer wasn't showing that, but I don't have it installed on this PC to check. Might also be worth mentioning which version of the database and PL/SQL Developer you're using, and exactly where you are looking at the DDL.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I was looking at the DDL through PL/SQL Developer.  A `desc` in PL*SQL does show the aliases but not what field they relate to.  I'm on Oracle 11.  PL/SQL Developer is 11.0.4.1774.  It sounds like I need to try `dbms_metadata.get_ddl`

Comment: There isn't anywhere that shows a mapping from the the view column name to the table column name, because there isn't necessarily a simple link - the view could be against an expression rather than a simple column. You're probably stuck with parsing the view's query to get the table column names and comparing with the view's column names - either also from the definition, or from `user_tab_columns` based on `column_id`. (You can't assume the `column_id` values for the table matches the view; they will in your example but don't have to and might not be safe to assume anything).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW myView (alias1, alias2) as select ixtbm, ixkit from f3002_wh;
```

I have to say though, if you can see the underlying view query then the obfuscation is a waste of time!

And what I assume is happening is that the DDL generated by your tool doesn't by default include the column list which is why you don't see it. If you dropped the view and rebuilt it with their generated DDL instead of using the script that originally created it and you would lose the aliases.

Their may be options on the DDL generator to include the column name list in views, but as I don't have that tool I cannot verify that. To do that they need to query ALL_TAB_COLUMNS rather than just showing the query from within the TEXT field of ALL_VIEWS.

Comment: it was indeed in `all_tab_columns`.  I incorrectly assumed that would show me the same content as the DDL from the IDE.  Many thanks.